Laravel join on max row by created_at
I'm currently building a filters section for a backend application and all the other filters work fine as they are less complicated, however, I've got to a point where I'm required to join a new table (one to many) but only return the latest result by date on the joined record.
In the code below, I am joining sites to companies (which works fine) and then joining meters to sites (which also works fine) but when we come to the contracts, we have one meter that can have many contracts. The only issue here is that I don't want to join every contract for each meter, I just want to join the latest one by created_at so I can check the supplier status.
if (! is_null($request->input('filters.suppliers'))) {
    $companies->join('sites as s1', 'companies.id', '=', 's1.company_id');
    $companies->join('meters as m1', 's1.id', '=', 'm1.site_id');

    $companies->join('contracts as c1', function ($join) use ($request) {
        $join->on('m1.id', '=', 'c1.meter_id');
        $join->whereIn('c1.supplier_id', $request->input('filters.suppliers'));
    });
}

I have seen many suggestions saying to use MAX(created_at) but this doesn't work as it just grabs the latest record in that entire table. I want to get the latest related record rather than the latest record in general.
I have tried having (select max(c1.created_at) from contracts where c1.meter_id = m1.id). I have also tried the same but working with ID's and having an extra select statement. I'm unsure which direction to take at this point.
I'm not really sure how to phrase the question however if you require more info or have question feel free to reply or comment.
Thanks in advance

Try the following where the subquery selects the id, meter_id, supplier_id, and created_at of the latest contract for each meter, ensuring that only the most recent contract (based on created_at) for each meter_id is selected using the whereRaw condition. The main query then joins this subquery using the meter_id field to get the latest contract for each meter. This will make sure that you only join the latest contract for each meter, rather than all contracts.
if (!is_null($request->input('filters.suppliers'))) {
    $companies->join('sites as s1', 'companies.id', '=', 's1.company_id')
              ->join('meters as m1', 's1.id', '=', 'm1.site_id');

    //Write a Subquery to get the latest contract for each meter
    $latestContracts = DB::table('contracts as c2')
        ->select('c2.id', 'c2.meter_id', 'c2.supplier_id', 'c2.created_at')
        ->whereIn('c2.supplier_id', $request->input('filters.suppliers'))
        ->whereRaw('c2.created_at = (SELECT MAX(c3.created_at) FROM contracts as c3 WHERE c3.meter_id = c2.meter_id)')
        ->toSql();

    //THEN Join the subquery with the main query
    $companies->join(DB::raw("($latestContracts) as c1"), function ($join) {
        $join->on('m1.id', '=', 'c1.meter_id');
    });
}


I'm going to upvote because 99% of it is correct and I'd have never have gotten it but the other 1% is that you get an invalid parameter SQL exception with the toSql function. It worked by changing this to toRawSql. Tested and worked perfectly! Thank you
